# How to set Python version by default in FreeBSD?

Tags: python, environment-variables, freebsd

I'm trying to install the application [node](https://github.com/joyent/node), but by default in my environment is *python 3*, and requires *python 2.6*. How can I change the default *python* version in *FreeBSD*?

```
# cd /usr/local/bin
# ls -l | grep python
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel  1246256 Jul 12  2011 python
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1401 Jul 12  2011 python-config
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     6060 Jul 12  2011 python-shared
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1408 Jul 12  2011 python-shared-config
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     3720 Jul 12  2011 python-shared2.6
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1431 Jul 12  2011 python-shared2.6-config
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     6060 Jul 12  2011 python-shared3.1
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1408 Jul 12  2011 python-shared3.1-config
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  1182056 Jul 12  2011 python2.6
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1424 Jul 12  2011 python2.6-config
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel  1246256 Jul 12  2011 python3.1
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1401 Jul 12  2011 python3.1-config
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could remove `/usr/local/bin/python` and create a symlink to Python 2.6:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/python
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: This has to be redone after every update of the default python! The post-install target in the port makefile hardlinks the version-specific binaries to the versionless binaries.

Comment: zeekay  You rock, my friend.  After the agony of trying to get this done and reading dozens of silly replies...  Most of the other replies try to tell you that you should not do this and that because...  But I am not able to install software which makes explicit calls to "python" expecting it to be wired to python3.6 or other.  So, the head games are useless.  Thank you  This works!  Thank you... thank you...

Answer (score 27):

You should remove the python meta-port `/usr/ports/lang/python`.
Then set the following variable in `/etc/make.conf`:

```
PYTHON_DEFAULT_VERSION='python3.2'
```

(If you want the latest version. Alternatively you can also use `python3.1`. Currently, the default is `python2.7`.)

Now install `/usr/ports/lang/python` again.
Note that ports can request another version of python!

**Update**: Since October 2013, there is a new way of setting default versions;

```
20131003:
  AFFECTS: users of lang/python* and ports
  AUTHOR: mva@FreeBSD.org

  The default versions of lang/python* have been changed to support the
  new DEFAULT_VERSIONS variable.

  PYTHON_DEFAULT_VERSION, PYTHON2_DEFAULT_VERSION and
  PYTHON3_DEFAULT_VERSION are deprecated. If you have set them in your
  make.conf, you should change them something like

  DEFAULT_VERSIONS=python=2.7 python2=2.7 python3=3.3
```

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer!!!! I knew this had changed and just about to google for the answer again when I saw the dated updated part of your answer.

Comment: Could you explain how one should remove a meta-port?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer as of FreeBSD 12.0 is as follows.

1. Create a file in `/tmp/makePatchPython3.6.patch` with the following contents:

```
1,2d0
< DEFAULT_VERSIONS += python=3.6
<
```

This will add a line to the start of your `/etc/make.conf` that will change the default python in use on the system.

```
[/usr/ports/lang/python]$ sudo make deinstall
[/usr/ports/lang/python]$ sudo patch /etc/make.conf /tmp/makePatchPython3.6.patch
[/usr/ports/lang/python]$ sudo make reinstall
[/usr/ports/lang/python]$ python --version
Python 3.6.8 # This will be different depending on which python version you install.
```

Answer (score -3):

```
mv python python.old

ln -s /usr/bin/pythonX.X  /usr/bin/python
```

in  X.X write your version